# Progressive measurability implies adaptedness

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Somehow this statement in the title is obvious according to many textbooks but I couldn't produce a rigorous proof of it. Here is what I have so far.

$(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ being a stochastic process and $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a filtration, I want to show that
$$A(B,t):=\{\omega \in \Omega: X_t(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$$
for arbitrary $t \in \mathbf{R}_+$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbf{R}$.

Since $X$ is progressively measurable, I have the following
$$P(B,t) =\{(s,\omega) \in [0,t]\times\Omega, X(s,\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{B}_{[0,t]}\otimes\mathcal{F}_t$$
for arbitrary $t \in \mathbf{R}_+$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbf{R}$.

I don't see how to proceed from here on without hand-waving arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progressive measurability means that the mapping

$$([0,t] \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}([0,t]) \times \mathcal{F}_t) \ni (s,\omega) \mapsto f(s,\omega) := X(s,\omega) \tag{1}$$

is measurable. On the other hand, the mapping

$$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t) \ni \omega \mapsto g(\omega) := (t,\omega) \in ([0,t] \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}([0,t]) \times \mathcal{F}_t) \tag{2}$$

is also measurable. This implies that

$$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t) \ni \omega \mapsto f \circ g(\omega) = f(t,\omega) = X(t,\omega)$$

is measurable as the composition of two measurable mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must say though that I find it a bit hard to "internalize" your reasoning even though I feel like I get your point. But referring back to my attempt and looking at the collection $P(B,t)$, if I applied some kind of projection to this collection that selects out the $\omega$s that are paired with $t$, would this resulting projection lie in $\mathcal{F}_t$? If yes, why?

Comment: @Calculon Well, in some sense that's what I'm doing. The set $$g^{-1}(P(B,t))$$ is the set of the $\omega$'s "which are paired with $t$".

Comment: So if I say $g^{-1}$, as a projection on $\Omega$, is measurable and  hence $g^{-1}(P(B,t))$ remains measurable on the $\sigma$-algebra defined on $\Omega$, which is $\mathcal{F}_t$, would it be sufficiently rigorous?

Comment: @Calculon $g$ isn't a projection; you really have to show that $g$ is measurable. *Then* you can conclude that $g^{-1}(P(B,t)) \in \mathcal{F}_t$.